# How to make Windows Hot Keys work in Direct X environments?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, directx, hotkeys

I am programming a really simple MFC C++ Application which is working with HotKeys. To set a HotKey I use the following method from the WinAPI for my application:

```
BOOL RegisterHotKey(
    HWND hWnd,         // window to receive hot-key notification
    int id,            // identifier of hot key
    UINT fsModifiers,  // key-modifier flags
    UINT vk            // virtual-key code
);
```

To catch any HotKey Message I use: `ON_MESSAGE(WM_HOTKEY,OnHotKey)` in the message map and this Callback Method to test it's functionality:

```
LRESULT OnHotKey(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (wParam == MY_HOTKEY_KEY_CODE)
    {
        MessageBox(L"HotKey was pressed!");
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

When a HotKey is pressed it enters the `OnHotKey` Method and does not process the key normally. For example if I write some text in Notepad and press "O" as HotKey, the "O" wont append to my text but the Message "HotKey was pressed!" appears, which is nice.

But when I am in any Direct X Game and press my HotKey, it is not sent to my application. Also when typing something in a Direct X environment the HotKey just works as normal key.
Is Direct X binding all key inputs somehow? Is there a way to make Windows HotKeys work with Direct X environments?

Comment: I suspect this is by design. Hotkeys are disabled when a DirectX application has focus.

Comment: Thats my guess aswell, but other applications such as "Fraps" work with hotkeys to record in game aswell. So there must be a way to get around this... :/